# Partial list unpack in Python

Tags: python

In Python, the assignment operator can unpack a list or a tuple into variables, like this:

```
l = (1, 2)
a, b = l # Here goes auto unpack
```

But I need to specify exactly the same amount of names to the left as an item count in the list to the right. But sometimes I don't know the size of the list to the right, for example, if I use split().

Example:

```
a, b = "length=25".split("=") # This will result in a="length" and b=25
```

But the following code will lead to an error:

```
a, b = "DEFAULT_LENGTH".split("=") # Error, list has only one item
```

Is it possible to somehow unpack the list in the example above so I can get a = "DEFAULT_LENGTH" and b equals to `None` or not set? A straightforward way looks kind of long:

```
a = b = None
if "=" in string :
  a, b = string.split("=")
else :
  a = string
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333680/extended-tuple-unpacking-in-python-2 general

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
# this will result in a="length" and b="25"
a, b = "length=25".partition("=")[::2]

# this will result in a="DEFAULT_LENGTH" and b=""
a, b = "DEFAULT_LENGTH".partition("=")[::2]
```

Comment: Today you should use unpacking. `a, *b = "length=25".split("=")` this equals: `a='length' ; b=['25']` if there's only 1 item, `b = []`. If there's more than one item, `b` is set to the entire remaining list. You can even do something like this  `first, *mid, last = "Hello world, welcome to the jungle!".split(" ")` they become `('Hello', ['world,', 'welcome', 'to', 'the'], 'jungle!')`

Answer (score 70):

This may be of no use to you unless you're using Python 3. However, for completeness, it's worth noting that the [extended tuple unpacking](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) introduced there allows you to do things like:

```
>>> a, *b = "length=25".split("=")
>>> a,b
("length", ['25'])
>>> a, *b = "DEFAULT_LENGTH".split("=")
>>> a,b
("DEFAULT_LENGTH", [])
```

I.e. tuple unpacking now works similarly to how it does in argument unpacking, so you can denote "the rest of the items" with `*`, and get them as a (possibly empty) list.

Partition is probably the best solution for what you're doing however.

Answer (score 7):

This is slightly better than your solution but still not very elegant; it wouldn't surprise me if there's a better way to do it.

```
a, b = (string.split("=") + [None])[:2]
```

Comment: Nice. Basically a home-grown version of partition.

Answer (score 6):

The nicest way is using the [partition string method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=partition#str.partition):

> Split the string at the first occurrence of sep, and return a 3-tuple containing the part before the separator, the separator itself, and the part after the separator. If the separator is not found, return a 3-tuple containing the string itself, followed by two empty strings.
>
> New in version 2.5.

```
>>> inputstr = "length=25"
>>> inputstr.partition("=")
('length', '=', '25')
>>> name, _, value = inputstr.partition("=")
>>> print name, value
length 25
```

It also works for strings not containing the `=`:

```
>>> inputstr = "DEFAULT_VALUE"
>>> inputstr.partition("=")
('DEFAULT_VALUE', '', '')
```

If for some reason you are using a version of Python before 2.5, you can use list-slicing to do much the same, if slightly less tidily:

```
>>> x = "DEFAULT_LENGTH"

>>> a = x.split("=")[0]
>>> b = "=".join(x.split("=")[1:])

>>> print (a, b)
('DEFAULT_LENGTH', '')
```

..and when `x = "length=25"`:

```
('length', '25')
```

Easily turned into a function or lambda:

```
>>> part = lambda x: (x.split("=")[0], "=".join(x.split("=")[1:]))
>>> part("length=25")
('length', '25')
>>> part('DEFAULT_LENGTH')
('DEFAULT_LENGTH', '')
```

Comment: I like this answer better than the selected one because it actually explains what partition does. The notation was not 100% intuitive at first glance.

Answer (score 4):

You could write a helper function to do it.

```
>>> def pack(values, size):
...     if len(values) >= size:
...         return values[:size]
...     return values + [None] * (size - len(values))
...
>>> a, b = pack('a:b:c'.split(':'), 2)
>>> a, b
('a', 'b')
>>> a, b = pack('a'.split(':'), 2)
>>> a, b
('a', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

> But sometimes I don't know a size of the list to the right, for example if I use split().

Yeah, when I've got cases with limit>1 (so I can't use partition) I usually plump for:

```
def paddedsplit(s, find, limit):
    parts= s.split(find, limit)
    return parts+[parts[0][:0]]*(limit+1-len(parts))

username, password, hash= paddedsplit(credentials, ':', 2)
```

(`parts[0][:0]` is there to get an empty ‘str’ or ‘unicode’, matching whichever of those the split produced. You could use None if you prefer.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this code, it is meant as a joke, but it does what you want:

```
a = b = None
try: a, b = [a for a in 'DEFAULT_LENGTH'.split('=')]
except: pass
```

Comment: Just wait till someone tries to extend it to work for 3 variables though (or use python3)!  Putting that in your code someone might read would be rather evil :-)  A more sane approach is possibly just putting a=theString in the except block.

Answer (score 0):

Many other solutions have been proposed, but I have to say the most straightforward to me is still

```
a, b = string.split("=") if "=" in string else (string, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, perhaps use a regular expression?

```
>>> import re
>>> unpack_re = re.compile("(\w*)(?:=(\w*))?")

>>> x = "DEFAULT_LENGTH"
>>> unpack_re.match(x).groups()
('DEFAULT_LENGTH', None)

>>> y = "length=107"
>>> unpack_re.match(y).groups()
('length', '107')
```

If you make sure the re.match() always succeeds, .groups() will always return the right number of elements to unpack into your tuple, so you can safely do

```
a,b = unpack_re.match(x).groups()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using this, but just for fun here's some code that actually does what you want. When you call `unpack(<sequence>)`, the `unpack` function uses the `inspect` module to find the actual line of source where the function was called, then uses the `ast` module to parse that line and count the number of variables being unpacked.

Caveats:

- For multiple assignment (e.g. `(a,b) = c = unpack([1,2,3])`), it only uses the first term in the assignment
- It won't work if it can't find the source code (e.g. because you're calling it from the repl)
- It won't work if the assignment statement spans multiple lines

Code:

```py
import inspect, ast
from itertools import islice, chain, cycle

def iter_n(iterator, n, default=None):
    return islice(chain(iterator, cycle([default])), n)

def unpack(sequence, default=None):
    stack = inspect.stack()
    try:
        frame = stack[1][0]
        source = inspect.getsource(inspect.getmodule(frame)).splitlines()
        line = source[frame.f_lineno-1].strip()
        try:
            tree = ast.parse(line, 'whatever', 'exec')
        except SyntaxError:
            return tuple(sequence)
        exp = tree.body[0]
        if not isinstance(exp, ast.Assign):
            return tuple(sequence)
        exp = exp.targets[0]
        if not isinstance(exp, ast.Tuple):
            return tuple(sequence)
        n_items = len(exp.elts)
        return tuple(iter_n(sequence, n_items, default))
    finally:
        del stack

# Examples
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Extra items are discarded
    x, y = unpack([1,2,3,4,5])
    assert (x,y) == (1,2)
    # Missing items become None
    x, y, z = unpack([9])
    assert (x, y, z) == (9, None, None)
    # Or the default you provide
    x, y, z = unpack([1], 'foo')
    assert (x, y, z) == (1, 'foo', 'foo')
    # unpack() is equivalent to tuple() if it's not part of an assignment
    assert unpack('abc') == ('a', 'b', 'c')
    # Or if it's part of an assignment that isn't sequence-unpacking
    x = unpack([1,2,3])
    assert x == (1,2,3)
    # Add a comma to force tuple assignment:
    x, = unpack([1,2,3])
    assert x == 1
    # unpack only uses the first assignment target
    # So in this case, unpack('foobar') returns tuple('foo')
    (x, y, z) = t = unpack('foobar')
    assert (x, y, z) == t == ('f', 'o', 'o')
    # But in this case, it returns tuple('foobar')
    try:
        t = (x, y, z) = unpack('foobar')
    except ValueError as e:
        assert str(e) == 'too many values to unpack'
    else:
        raise Exception("That should have failed.")
    # Also, it won't work if the call spans multiple lines, because it only
    # inspects the actual line where the call happens:
    try:
        (x, y, z) = unpack([
            1, 2, 3, 4])
    except ValueError as e:
        assert str(e) == 'too many values to unpack'
    else:
        raise Exception("That should have failed.")
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
values = aString.split("=")
if len(values) == 1:
   a = values[0]
else:
   a, b = values
```