# How to Separate Output Data

Tags: python, regex, parsing, pyparsing

Here is my code:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        Mocha Rotoscoping Via Blender
# Purpose:     Make rotoscoping more efficient
#
# Author:      Jeff Owens
#
# Created:     11/07/2011
# Copyright:   (c) jeff.owens 2011
# Licence:     Grasshorse
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import os
import parser
sys.path.append('Z:\_protomotion\Prog\HelperScripts')
import GetDir
sys.path.append('Z:/Blender_Roto')
filename = 'diving_board.shape4ae'
infile = 'Z:/Blender_Roto/'
#import bpy
#from mathutils import Vector

#below are taken from mocha export
x_width =2048
y_height = 778
z_depth = 0
frame = 20

import re

data_directory = 'Z:/Blender_Roto/' # windows
data_file = 'diving_board.shape4ae'
fullpath = data_directory + data_file


print("====init=====")

file = open(fullpath)
for line in file:
current_line = line

# massive room for optimized code here.

# this assumes the last element of the line containing the words
# "Units Per Second" is the number we are looking for.
# this is a non float number, generally.
if current_line.find("Units Per Second") != -1:
    fps = line_split = float(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Frames Per Second:", fps)

# source dimensions
if current_line.find("Source Width") != -1:
    source_width = line_split = int(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Source Width:", source_width)

if current_line.find("Source Height") != -1:
    source_height = line_split = int(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Source Height:", source_height)

# aspect ratios
if current_line.find("Source Pixel Aspect Ratio") != -1:
    source_px_aspect = line_split = int(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Source Pixel Aspect Ratio:", source_px_aspect)

if current_line.find("Comp Pixel Aspect Ratio") != -1:
    comp_aspect = line_split = int(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Comp Pixel Aspect Ratio:", comp_aspect)


# assumption, ae file can contain multiple mocha shapes.
# without knowing the exact format i will limit the script
# to deal with one mocha shape being animated N frames.

# this gathers the shape details, and frame number but does not
# include error checking yet.
if current_line.find("XSpline") != -1:

    # record the frame number.

    frame = re.search("\s*(\d*)\s*XSpline", current_line)
    if frame.group(1) != None:
        frame = frame.group(1)
        print("frame:", frame)


    # pick part the part of the line that deals with geometry
    match = re.search("XSpline\((.+)\)\n", current_line)

    line_to_strip = match.group(1)
    points = re.findall('(\(.*?\))', line_to_strip)
    print(len(points))
    for point in points:
        print(point)

 file.close()
```

here is the output:

```
====init=====
Frames Per Second: 24.0
Source Width: 2048
Source Height: 778
Source Pixel Aspect Ratio: 1
Comp Pixel Aspect Ratio: 1
frame: 20
5
(0.793803,0.136326,0,0.5,0)
(0.772345,0.642332,0,0.5,0)
(0.6436,0.597615,0,0.5,0)
(0.70082,0.143387,0,0.5,0.25)
(0.70082,0.112791,0,0.5,0)
```

I want to figure out how to call out individual points given. For example, how would I have the code just spit out 0.793803, or just spit out 0.136326, etc etc

**ADDENDUM**

So what I ended up doing was adding this

```
(point1, point2, point3, point4, point5) = points
print (point1)
#print (point2)
#print (point3)
#print (point4)
#print (point5)
```

which yielded:

```
(0.793803,0.136326,0,0.5,0)
```

But when I tried to parse again and I wrote

```
(x,y,z,w,s) = p
```

it came up with the error p is not defined

so then I tried
    (x,y,z,w,s) = point1

which yielded the error too many values to unpack.

Another thing I tried was

```
for point1 in points
    p1x = (x,)
print (p1x)
```

which just yielded the first ( rather than the whole X value...

Any solutions?

**ADDENDUM PT 2**

So what happens is this:

```
====init=====
Frames Per Second: 24.0
Source Width: 2048
Source Height: 778
Source Pixel Aspect Ratio: 1
Comp Pixel Aspect Ratio: 1
5
frame: 20
(0.793803,0.136326,0,0.5,0)
x: (, y: y0
x: (, y: y0
x: (, y: y0
x: (, y: y0
x: (, y: y0
```

when I input this

```
(point1, point2, point3, point4, point5) = points
print (point1)
#print (point2)
#print (point3)
#print (point4)
#print (point5)

for point in points:
    x, y, *data = point
    print(str.format("x: {0}, y: y{1}", x, y))

file.close()
```

I don't know why it is pulling (, from (0.793803,0.136326,0,0.5,0)

I can tell you that the program thinks that if I put x, y, z, w, s

I want x: '(' y: '0'  z: '.'  w: '7' s: '9' 
which I don't,
I want: 
x: 0.793803
y: 0.136326
z: 0
w: 0.5
s: 0

Sorry for all the questions, I *really* appreciate your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967426/elegant-unpacking-variable-length-tuples is similar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299682/how-to-unpack-tuple-of-length-n-to-mn-variables is probably the most informative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The points are tuples, so it's rather simple.

You can unpack them first (where p is a point):

```
>>> x, y, *data = p
>>> x
0.793803
>>> y
0.136326
>>> data
[0, 0.5, 0]
```

Or you can index into them:

```
>>> p[0]
0.793803
```

Or you can go crazy with string formatting:

```
>>> str.format("x{0[0]} y{0[1]}", p)
'x0.793803 y0.136326'
```

Ok, maybe not that last one. I would unpack them first for readability.

---

My example in context:

```
for point in points:
    x, y, *data = point
    print(str.format("x: {0}, y: y{1}", x, y))
```

`points` is an "iterable" of tuples, each tuple representing a point on the spline, captured into the variable `point`.

Comment: I tried a few different things, got a little progress, but could you look back at the original post, I posted an Addendum with things I tried

Comment: @Jeff: I see, well my suggestion is that you'd do any of the above examples inside the for-loop. Added an example. Perhaps I've misunderstood you.

Comment: @Jeff: about too many values to unpack. When you unpack a list or tuple it needs as many "target variables" as there is values in the list or tuple. The exception is of course if you do something like `a, *rest = (...)`, everything after the first element will end up in a list in `rest`.

Comment: thanks for the quick response, I'll let you know how it works out

Comment: I ran into yet another problem.. I posted it in addendum pt2... sorry for being a pest

Comment: @Jeff: You don't need to unpack `points`. It's an iterable, you can iterate over it with the for-loop (you can with tuples too, but it's usually less desirable) as you all-ready do :) Why you are getting `(` though; I'm not sure, could it be something your regex captures from input?