# How to unpack tuple of length n to m<n variables

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

In Python 3 I can do the following (see also [PEP3132](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) on Extended Iterable Unpacking):

```
a, *b = (1, 2, 3)
# a = 1; b = (2, 3)
```

What can I do to achieve the same similarly elegant in Python 2.x?

---

I know that I could use single element access and slicing operations, but I wonder if there is a more *pythonic* way. My code so far:

```
a, b = (1, 2, 3)[0], (1, 2, 3)[1:]
# a = 1; b = (2, 3)
```

Comment: Seems like the explicit slicing is it, or using mutiple anonymous _ underscore vars to capture unwanted values:  x, _, _ = tup

Comment: I actually have a question about this feature. Does it comply with the zen of python's "Explicit is better than implicit."?

Comment: @jdi it explicitly states: get me the first item to `a` and all other items to `b`. I find this very clear ...

Comment: this is probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5333680/1025391

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found out that the related [PEP3132](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) gives some examples for Python 2.x as well:

> Many algorithms require splitting a sequence in a "first, rest" pair:
>
> ```
> first, rest = seq[0], seq[1:]
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Also, if the right-hand value is not a list, but an iterable, it has to be converted to a list before being able to do slicing; to avoid creating this temporary list, one has to resort to
>
> ```
> it = iter(seq)
> first = it.next()
> rest = list(it)
> ```

---

Other approaches given in the answers to this question:

**Function Argument List Unpacking Approach**

requires an extra function definition/call:

```
def unpack(first, *rest): 
  return first, rest
first, rest = unpack( *seq )
```

I wonder why it is implemented in unpacking function argument lists but not for normal tuple unpacking.

**Generator Approach**

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10300081/1025391). Also requires a custom function implementation. Is a little more flexible concerning the number of *first* variables.

```
def unpack_nfirst(seq, nfirst):
  it = iter(seq)
  for x in xrange(nfirst):
    yield next(it, None)
  yield tuple(it)
first, rest = unpack_nfirst(seq, 1)
```

---

The most pythonic would probably be the ones mentioned in the PEP above, I guess?

Comment: As of today PEP 3132 only appears to apply to Python 3.x. I can confirm that the 'first, *rest = seq' syntax does not work in Python 2.7.5 (you mention 2.x above).

Comment: @Dave Thanks for bringing this up again. I decided to remove the section from the quoted part, because it was a source of confusion and just not relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 24):

I may be wrong but as far as I know

```
a, *b = (1, 2, 3)
```

is just syntactic sugar for slicing and indexing tuples. I find it useful but not very explicit.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I'm still on py2.7 and haven't seen this 3.x addition yet. And it doesn't even look that much more useful than a slice. You obviously know you want the first element. Much prefer the slicing to the sugar.

Comment: while it may be just sugar, it becomes more important if your list on the left is larger than 2 (well, maybe larger than 6 or 7). The problem with slices is that you have to do some manual counting on both sides of the `=` which potentially makes the code harder to maintain.

Comment: I have a list of lists, each of which of length 4 or more, and I wish I could do this in python2.7: `for a, b, c, d, *unused in myList: <do work with a, b, c, d>`. With appropriate names for a, b, c, d, I find it more expressive than having to index a single variable.

Comment: @mcmlxxxvi indeed, naming is (hard) and better. I recant my statement.

Answer (score 8):

I've got this handy little function:

```
def just(n, seq):
    it = iter(seq)
    for _ in range(n - 1):
        yield next(it, None)
    yield tuple(it)
```

For example:

```
a, b, c = just(3, range(5))
print a, b, c
## 0 1 (2, 3, 4)
```

also works with less arguments:

```
a, b, c = just(3, ['X', 'Y'])
print a, b, c
## X Y ()
```

In response to the comment, you can also define:

```
def take2(a, *rest): return a, rest
def take3(a, b, *rest): return a, b, rest
def take4(a, b, c, *rest): return a, b, rest
... etc
```

and use it like this:

```
p = (1,2,3)
a, b = take2(*p)
print a, b
## 1 (2, 3)
```

Comment: That brings me to the idea: `def foo(x, *y): return x, y` and it would be `a, b = foo( *(1,2,3) )` ...

Comment: @moooeeeep Good idea but you can simply do `a,b = foo(1,2,3)` instead of `a, b = foo( *(1,2,3) )`

Comment: in production code in which file do you keep this handy little function? same file? different file? import what? do you package it and its friends? so in overall, how does it look in real code when you access `just`?

Comment: @naxa: for example `import myTools .... a,b = myTools.just(...)`

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is any better way than the one you posted but here is an alternative using `iter`

```
>>> x = (1,2,3)
>>> i = iter(x)
>>> a,b = next(i), tuple(i)
>>> a
1
>>> b
(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the context, but what about .pop(0)?

I see that there are tuples in your example, but if you want to do the sort of stuff you do, lists would be more suited, I think? (Unless there is some good reason for them to be immutable not given in the question.)

```
b = [1,2,3]
a = b.pop(0)
```