# How do I change a singular element of a python list to a string

Tags: python, string, list

Say I have a python list with 5 elements; list = ['a','b','c','d','e']. And I want to change it into 5 different strings so that each element is its own string, for example,
str1 = a str2 = b str3 = c str4 = d str5 = e
How would that be done?
Note: I would want it to be done autonomously if possible as the number of elements in a list is variable according to the data that is input at the beginning of the original code.

Comment: Why can't you use `str1=mylist[0]`, `str2=mylist[1]`, etc. ?

Comment: You may want to do list unpacking: `a, b, c, d, e = ['a','b','c','d','e']`

Comment: I'd be curious to know when `str1`, `str2`, etc. is preferable to `s[1]` , `s[2]`. It sounds like you are about to make a mistake you will later regret. If you do this "autonomously", how will you know if you can safely access `str87`?

Comment: Check [generating variable names on fly in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python). Maybe just give a more meaningful name to your list (for instance `str` and there you have your variables `str[0], str[1]`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
list_ = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

You can use something called [`list unpacking`](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-unpack-list/), that you can do this way:

```
a, b, c, d, e = list_
```

---

As @[`Mark`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3874623/mark) told you in the comments...

> *I'd be curious to know when `str1`, `str2`, etc. is preferable to `s[1]` , `s[2]`. It sounds like you are about to make a mistake you will later regret.*

...you should avoid this approach.

---

If you don't know the lenght, you should read [`this`](https://medium.com/@davemcsavvii/unpacking-elements-from-iterables-of-unknown-length-363c510530d), which suggests you to use the `*` star operator...

```
first, second, *others, third, fourth = names
```

...until you have the whole list unpacked.

Since you don't want to write an hell of `if`/`elif`/`else` over the lenght, I would suggest you to use `exec` to [`create variables on fly`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010840/generating-variable-names-on-fly-in-python), even if (like Mark said) it's a bad idea.

---

I really want you to get that this is a **bad** idea, but you can use unpacking for useful scopes, in this case I would suggest you to read [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333680/extended-tuple-unpacking-in-python-2), [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299682/how-to-unpack-tuple-of-length-n-to-mn-variables) and the respective [`PEP`](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/).