# elegant unpacking variable-length tuples

Tags: python, tuples

A real, if silly problem:

https://github.com/joshmarshall/tornadorpc/blob/master/tornadorpc/base.py

```
def start_server(handlers, ...):
    ...
    for (route, handler) in handlers:
        ...
```

Normally "handlers" is a list of 2-element tuples. But with this particular solution (Tornado) you can pass a third argument to a particular handler (kw args). So a tuple in "handlers" may have 2 elems sometimes or 3 elems other times.

I need to unpack this in a loop. Sure, I can do smth like length checking or try..except on unpacking. Ugh.

Can you think of smth better/more clever than this:

```
In [8]: handlers
Out[8]: [(1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7)]


In [9]: new_handlers = [x + (None,) for x in handlers]
```

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If that handler takes keyword arguments, then use a dictionary for the third element:

```
handlers = [(1, 2, {}), (3, 4, {'keyword': 5), (6, 7, {})]

for route, handler, kwargs in handlers:
    some_method(route, handler, **kwargs)
```

Or you can apply the arguments using `*args` syntax; in that case just catch *all* values in the loop:

```
for args in handlers:
    some_method(*args)
```

If you *have* to unpack into at least 2 arguments, do so in a separate step:

```
for handler in handlers:
    route, handler, args = (handler[0], handler[1], handler[2:])
```

where `args` would be a tuple of 0 or more elements.

In Python 3, you can handle arbitrary width unpacking with a splat (`*`) target:

```
for route, handlers, *args in handlers:
```

where `*args` captures 0 or more *extra* values in the unpack.

The other route, to elements in `handlers` to a minimal length could be done with:

```
[(h + (None,) * 3)[:3] for h in handlers]
```

Demo:

```
>>> handlers = [(1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7)]
>>> [(h + (None,) * 3)[:3] for h in handlers]
[(1, 2, None), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, None)]
```

Comment: I know but handler is not my problem, my problem is "for" loop over sequence of variable length tuples. (and since tornadorpc is not my code/project I'm interested more in general solution to this sort of problem rather than particular tornado/tornadorpc)

Comment: @JohnDoe: But the problem *goes away* if you treat it differently. In any case, I added generic options already.

Answer (score 3):

Since Python 3 you can use [PEP 3132](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) extended unpacking:

```
for route, handler, *kw in handlers:
    ...
```

If that isn't an option, unpack with an intermediary:

```
for handler in handlers:
    (route, handler), kw = handler[:2], handler[2:]
```

Comment: Your unpack line fails with `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack`, because you have a tuple of two values on the right-hand-side.

Comment: Sorry but that does not quite work: ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack. I can get around by doing (r, h), kw = h[:2], h[2:] but then kw is a tuple itself (like (5,) or ()).