# Idiomatic way to unpack variable length list of maximum size n

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I'm reading a file and unpacking each line like this:

```
for line in filter(fh):
  a, b, c, d = line.split()
```

However, it's possible that line may have more or fewer columns than the variables I wish to unpack. In the case when there are fewer, I'd like to assign `None` to the dangling variables, and in the case where there are more, I'd like to ignore them. What's the idiomatic way to do this? I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: Good question. I hope that somebody proves me wrong, but I think that you would need more than one statement for that... It's do-able in Lua as far as I remember...

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333680/extended-tuple-unpacking-in-python-2

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Fix the length of the list, padding with `None`.

```
def fixLength(lst, length):
    return (lst + [None] * length)[:length]
```

Answer (score 8):

In python 3 you can use this

```
a, b, c, d, *_unused_ = line.split() + [None]*4
```

**Edit**

For large strings I suggest to use `maxsplit`-argument for split (this argument also works in py2.7):

```
a, b, c, d, *_unused_ = line.split(None, 4) + [None]*4
```

<strike>Why 5? Otherwise the 4th element would consist the whole residual of the line.</strike>

**Edit2** It is 4… It stops after 4 splits, not 4 elements

Comment: @Marcin And I didn't get it in your case either.

Comment: That's a nice feature of python 3 which I wish I could use! Alas, python 2

Comment: At least as of python 2.7.5, `str.split` takes maxsplit as a positional, not keyword argument. So it is `line.split(None, 5)`, but still a good addition.

Comment: @pythonicmetaphor You are right. Changed it, so the split will work in both versions. And my explanation for the maxsplit-number was wrong, changed it, too. Sorry for all this confusion...

Comment: I upvoted this as a one-off solution, but as a non-python developer, this is honestly ugly AF. How can't such a "well-thought language" solve this through actual syntax?

Answer (score 5):

First of all, think about why you want to do this.

However, given that you want to (1) pad with `None` and (2) ignore extra variables, the code is easy:

```
a,b,c,d = (line.split() + [None]*4)[:4]
```

Obviously, the magic number has to be the same as the number of variables. This will extend what you have with the magic number, then trim back down to that length.

For an arbitrary iterable you can do:

```
import itertools

def padslice(seq,n):
    return itertools.islice(itertools.chain(seq,itertools.repeat(None)), n)
```

This is the same pad-and-slice with itertools.

Comment: +1 for the python-2.7-one-liner. (Not compensatory, seriously).
But have a look at your padslice-function. It does not return a sequence, but I think in order to unpack you will need a list or something like this.

Comment: @koffein You can unpack from a generator, so there is no issue.

Comment: Your first answer is similar to what I was doing, which is works, but doesn't feel quite idiomatic, because it doesn't work with iterators. But I like your second answer, which is getting much closer to feeling pythonic to me.

Comment: @Marcin Right. Tested it and it worked… Nice feature

Comment: @pythonicmetaphor Idiomatic python doesn't have to work with iterators, especially where the type is known not to be an iterator. But, thanks.

Comment: Well, in this case, unpacking tuples works with iterators, so I expected the 'right' solution to this problem to also work with iterators, thought maybe that's not true.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, you can use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), like this:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

max_params = 4

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a, b, c, d = next(zip(*zip_longest(lst, range(max_params))))
print(f'{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}') # 1, 2, 3, 4

lst = [1, 2, 3]
a, b, c, d = next(zip(*zip_longest(lst, range(max_params))))
print(f'{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}') # 1, 2, 3, None
```

For Python 2.x you can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21483499/2411320).

Answer (score -1):

Something like this, works for any iterable/iterator. If you're always going to pass a list then you can remove the `islice` part.

```
from itertools import islice
def solve(seq, n):
    lis = list(islice(seq, n))
    return lis + [None]*(n - len(lis))
... 
>>> a, b, c, d = solve(range(2), 4)
>>> a, b, c, d
(0, 1, None, None)
>>> a, b, c, d = solve('qwe', 4)
>>> a, b, c, d
('q', 'w', 'e', None)
>>> a, b, c, d = solve(iter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), 4)
>>> a, b, c, d
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Can you rename the function so that it looks like something you will use all around your code, *idiomatically* ?

Comment: Why slice before padding?

Comment: @Marcin To support iterators as well, if iterator contains more than `n` items then there's no need to read all of them.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary With itertools you don't read ahead. That's the point.

Comment: @Marcin I am converting that iterator to a list first, so a slice is required.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Don't do that, then.