# How to unpack optional items from a tuple?

Tags: python, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I have a list of some input values, of which the first couple of mandatory and the last couple optional.  Is there any easy way to use tuple unpacking to assign these to variables, getting None if the optional parameters are missing.

eg.

```
a = [1,2]   
foo, bar, baz = a
# baz == None
```

ideally a could be any length - including longer than 3 (other items thrown away).

At the moment I'm using zip with a list of parameter names to get a dictionary:

```
items = dict(zip(('foo', 'bar', 'baz'), a))
foo = items.get('foo', None)
bar = items.get('bar', None)
baz = items.get('baz', None)
```

but it's a bit long-winded.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the linked question, this works:

```
foo, bar, baz == (list(a) + [None]*3)[:3]
```

Comment: I think you mean `foo, bar, baz = (a + [None]*3)[:3]`

Answer (score 5):

What about using Try Except:

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> try:
...     foo, bar, baz = a
... except:
...     foo, bar = a
...
>>>
```

Comment: This is so clearly the easiest solution

Comment: Danger, what happens if "= a" is not so simple, maybe you have a method call, maybe an database access? 

your "catch all" except swallows all errors, silently.

Comment: Should be `except ValueError:`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `itertools.izip_longest`:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
max_params = 3
args = (1, 2)

foo, bar, baz = zip(*izip_longest(args, range(max_params)))[0]
```

I should note that if you find yourself having to do this, though, you should probably consider storing the parameters in a `dict` instead of unpacking them into variables.

**Update**:
Since you're stuck with 2.5, try the following:

```
max_params = 3
args = (1, 2)

def unpack(args, param_length):
    return args + tuple(None for _ in range(param_length - len(args)))

foo, bar, baz = unpack(args, max_params)
```

Comment: Nice - unfortunately I'm stuck at Python 2.5 so this one isn't available to me :(