# How to handle variable length sublist unpacking in Python2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, nested-lists

How to handle variable length sublist unpacking in **Python2**?

In Python3, if I have variable sublist length, I could use this idiom:

```
>>> x = [(1, 2,3,4,5), (2, 4,6), (3, 5,6,7,8,9)]
>>> for i, *item in x:
...     print (item)
... 
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 6]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

In Python2, it's an invalid syntax:

```
>>> x = [(1, 2,3,4,5), (2, 4,6), (3, 5,6,7,8,9)]
>>> for i, *item in x:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    for i, *item in x:
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

BTW, this question is a little different from [Idiomatic way to unpack variable length list of maximum size n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20501440/idiomatic-way-to-unpack-variable-length-list), where the solution requires the knowledge of a fixed length.

And this question is specific to resolving the problem in Python2.

Comment: Duplicate of [Extended tuple unpacking in Python 2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5333680/2301450)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 2 does not have the splat syntax (`*item`). The simplest and the most intuitive way is the long way around:

```
for row in x:
    i = row[0]
    item = row[1:]
```

Comment: or on one line `i, item = row[0], row[1:]` which I personally prefer

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning on using this construct a lot it may be worthwhile writing a little helper:

```
def nibble1(nested):
    for vari in nested:
        yield vari[0], vari[1:]
```

then you could write your loop

```
for i, item in nibble1(x):
    etc.
```

But I somehow doubt you'll find that elegant enough...

Answer (score 1):

You also can do this:

```
x = [(1, 2,3,4,5), (2, 4,6), (3, 5,6,7,8,9)]

for lista in x:
  print (lista[1:])
```

Or using list comprehension as well:

```
x = [(1, 2,3,4,5), (2, 4,6), (3, 5,6,7,8,9)]

new_li = [item[1:] for item in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try This:-

```
x = [(1, 2,3,4,5), (2, 4,6), (3, 5,6,7,8,9)]
for item in x:
    print (list(item[1:]))
```