# how to assign variable values directly from list range

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a better and more pythonic way to this piece of code:

```
for i in rows:
    row_data = i.findAll('td')
    serial = row_data[0]
    hostname = row_data[1]
    owner = row_data[2]
    memory = row_data[3]
    processor = row_data[4]
    os = row_data[5]
    model = row_data[6]
    ip = row_data[7]
```

i'm trying to do something like this:

```
 [serial, hostname, owner, memory, etc..] = row_data[:7]
```

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

With or without index i get this message:
    [serial, hostname, owner, memory, processor, os, model, be_ip] = row_data
    ValueError: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do exactly that:

```
>>> row_data = ['serial', 'hostname', 'ip']
>>> [serial, hostname, ip] = row_data
>>> serial
'serial'
>>> hostname
'hostname'
>>> ip
'ip'
```

The square brackets around `[serial, hostname, ip]` are optional.

Comment: Worth mentioning that it's called [unpacking](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples#Packing_and_Unpacking)

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that `a,b,*tail = (1,2,3,4)` also works fine.

Comment: @Hyperboreus, is that version dependent? (It didn't work and I'm on 2.7.6)

Comment: @wnnmaw My bad, seems to be python3 only.

Comment: @wnnmaw: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333680/extended-tuple-unpacking-in-python-2

Comment: How come this isn't working for me? 
    [serial, hostname, owner, memory, processor, os, model, be_ip] =  row_data
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: @ZeroSoul13: You have eight variables on the left hand side, and `row_data` contains more than eight values.

Comment: Worked. corrected the index [:7] to [:8] and it worked. Thank you for your help. should have seen this one.