# Unpack a list in Python

Tags: list, python-2.6

Say I have a MySQL table I access through MySQLDB. I have a standard

```
SELECT statement:
sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE \
       WHERE INCOME > '%d'" % (1000)
```

I then execute it with the cursor and pluck out the columns as below.

```
   cursor.execute(sql)
   results = cursor.fetchall()
   for row in results:
      fname = row[0]
      lname = row[1]
      age = row[2]
      sex = row[3]
      income = row[4]
```

Is it possible to assign all the column names in a single statement? Something like:

```
for row in results:
    fname, lname, age, sex, income = unpack(row)
```

I could always do:

```
fname, lname, age, sex, income = row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]
```

But I have over 30 columns in my table and this is getting painful.
Note that though I'm using MySQL right now, I'd like this to be as DB agnostic as possible; our benevolent overlords might decide to port everything over to another database at any point.

Comment: You should remove references to SQL in your question, since it's really irrelevant. You have an array you want to deconstruct; it doesn't matter how you got the data.

Comment: why do you not simply write `for fname, lname, age, sex, income in results:`?

Comment: You might want to reconsider `SELECT *` if you're expecting a fixed number and order of columns, if the table layout changes you'll break things.

Comment: you can even consider running a `PRAGMA table_info()` query on the table to get a look at the number of columns and header names

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do:

```
fname, lname, age, sex, income = row
```

if `len(row)==5` it should works, otherwise, if you have python 3 you can use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

```
fname, lname, age, sex, income, *other = row
```

`other` will be a list of all remaining elements.

If you have python 2:
You can use a small function as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5333829/3297428):

```
def unpack_list(a, b, c, d, e, *f):
    return a, b, c, d, e, f

fname, lname, age, sex, income, other = unpack_list(*row)
```

If you only want the 5 first elements, as @Ev.Kounis meant, you can do:

```
fname, lname, age, sex, income = row[:5]
```

Comment: you can also add an asterisk to any of those (preferably the last) to make sure that even if there are more, execution will go on. Slicing `row` would also be an option since it doesnt throw errors when e.g., `[1,2,3][:5]`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I edited, but I believe it's python 3 only.

Comment: `fname, lname, age, sex, income = row[:5]` works in both Python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

How about an entirely different approach?

You could use a `DictCursor` and reference things by name. E.g,

```
cursor = db.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
for row in results:
    function_with_fname(row['fname'])
    function_with_age(row['age'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
results = [[1,2,3,4,5],
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
[True, False, True, False, True]
]

for one, two, three, four, five in results:
    print one, two, three, four, five
>>> 1 2 3 4 5
>>> a b c d e
>>> True False True False True
```

You could also unpack the values in your `for` loop itself.