# Make an input optional in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get two variables from one input like this:

```
x, y = input().split()
print(x, y)
```

But I want to make the `y` variable optional, so if the user only inputs `x` it would only print that value. I get a `ValueError` if only inserted the x argument.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is Python 3, here's two lines using extended iterable unpacking.

```
x, *y = input().split()
y = y[0] if y else ''
```

Comment: Thanks! I dont fully understand what that does but it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

You could use something different from `split` to 'fake' optional input. Using `str.partition` you could just catch the first and last element of the resulting tuple:

```
x, _, y = input().partition(' ')
```

and then `print` accordingly:

```
print(x, y if y else '')
```

`x` contains the first value of the input string (after it is splitted on `' '` while `y` contains the rest.

Comment: `x, y = input().partition(' ')[::2]` as in the suggested dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749070/partial-list-unpack-in-python

Comment: @Chris_Rands I would personally stick with the throw-away instead of going with a slice, it's not worth it in my view at least. (p.s: Hammered, thanks for pointing it out!)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot unpack your variables at once, you have to check size of the returned `list` object first. If size isn't 2, just fill with default, else proceed unpacking as you did.

```
toks = input().split()
if len(toks)==2:
    x,y = toks
else:
    x = toks[0]
    y = "default"

print(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y     = None
x     = input()

if ' ' in x:
    x, y = x.split()

print(x, y)
```

Comment: consider providing an explanation to your code

Answer (score 0):

You can go:

```
x, y = (list(input().split()) + [None]*2)[:2]
print(x, y if y else '')
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner way of doing this:

```
x, y, *z = input().split() + ['']
print(x, y)
```

Comment: But then you'll get a "too many values to unpack" error if the user enters two values.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I updated the code.