# Split one list into two lists just by unpacking?

Tags: python, list, split

I can split a list by slicing, but how to do it by unpacking?

#### What I have

When unpack, I'm getting one list and one string.

```
mylist=["start","next1","next2","next3","end"]


# Desired Result - two lists 
part1, part2= mylist[:-1],[mylist[-1]]
print(f"Slicing 2: {type(part1)} {part1} {type(part2)} {part2}")

# Not the desired result - one list and one string
*part1,part2 = mylist
print(f"Unpacking: {type(part1)} {part1} {type(part2)} {part2}")
```

Result:

```
Slicing: <class 'list'> ['start', 'next1', 'next2', 'next3'] <class 'list'> ['end']  
Unpacking: <class 'list'> ['start', 'next1', 'next2', 'next3'] <class 'str'> end
```

How to split a list into two lists just by unpacking?

Comment: The answer is no, you cannot split a list into two lists with unpacking.  At best you would have to add an extra line `part2 = [part2]`.

Comment: If you have a method that gives you your desired output (slicing), why do you want to use a different one (unpacking)? Is slicing doing something wrong?

Comment: Side note: `[mylist[-1]]` could also be accomplished with slicing `mylist[-1:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate [Steven Rumbalski's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74154874/split-one-list-into-two-lists-just-by-unpacking/74155125#comment130925773_74154874):

#### Unpacking with remainder `*`

Unpacking with `*part1,part2 = mylist` will split the list into the last item `part2` (which is a `str`) and the remaining items into `part1` (remainder denoted by asterisk `*`). See [Partial list unpack in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749070/partial-list-unpack-in-python).

#### Wrapping an item into a list

The *slicing* with index `mylist[-1]` also results in a single item of type `str`. But you **wrapped it into a list** by surrounding with brackets:

```
# Desired Result - two lists 
part1, part2= mylist[:-1],[mylist[-1]]  # see after the comma
```

This can also be done in two separate statements when *unpacking*:

```
>>> *first_items, last_item = mylist
>>> print(first_items, [last_item])  # the last item is wrapped as list
['start', 'next1', 'next2', 'next3'] ['end']
```

Note the `[last_item]` which wraps the item into a new list.

#### An expressive and simple way

As Steven side-noted, you can use the slicing-colon `:` to get new lists:

```
# `-1` is the index where the list is split
# `:` will take elements before or after the index into a new list
first_parts, last_parts = mylist[:-1], mylist[-1:]  # results in two lists
```

This way, you can easily adjust the split-position:

```
split_index = -1  # split before last item
first_parts, last_parts = mylist[:split_index], mylist[split_index:]  # results in two lists
print(first_parts, last_parts, sep='\n')
```

Result:

```
['start', 'next1', 'next2', 'next3']
['end']
```

Or even have 2 splits resulting in 3 lists:

```
first = 1  # split after firs item
last = -1  # split before last item
first_parts, middle_parts, last_parts = mylist[:first], mylist[first:last], mylist[last:]  # 3 lists
print(first_parts, middle_parts, last_parts, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
['start']
['next1', 'next2', 'next3']
['end']
```